# gmail account emails only appear in iCloud Inbox

Tags: icloud, mail.app, gmail

This has apparently been going on for some time but I didn't notice it until today.

I use Apple Mail (Sierra) as my mail client.  Any emails I receive to either of my two Gmail accounts, are only visible under the iCloud Inbox folder.  They are labeled as existing in that folder when I do a search, and I can see them as long as that's what I'm viewing (or have rules based on that Inbox).  But if I go to the actual Gmail account inboxes, none of the messages are there.

Why is this happening and how can I stop it?  I tried removing a Gmail account and re-adding it from scratch in System Prefs, but nothing changed.

To add some clarity, here is a picture showing my Inboxes - 1 for iCloud, and 2 for Gmail.  All emails sent to or from the Gmail addresses (via the mail.app client) appear under the iCloud Inbox (or sent mail) and do NOT appear under the appropriate Gmail Inboxes.

If I scroll down further, I see the second image, which clearly shows that the Gmail Inboxes don't even have all the usual Gmail folders below them, only Important and Chats, but nothing else.  So what gives here?

[image: My Inboxes]
[image: Gmail Inboxes Detail]

Comment: you can not have two gmails accounts showing in same folder on iCloud

Comment: Not sure what you are referring to. I have two separate Gmail accounts each with their own folders in the mail client. But all emails sent to those addresses are appearing in my single iCloud inbox folder

Comment: I thought that is what you said, and what Folder is that on iCloud ? And what is confusing you say you do not see them on your WEB based gmail account (not the Apple Mail).

Comment: Nowhere did I refer to my web mail. I do not use the web based email client for anything, ever.   I am referring strictly to the Apple mail client. In the sidebar it shows folders for each account, each one has its own inbox. But all the emails in my Gmail accounts, show up in the inbox for iCloud.

Comment: Gmail is a web mail. So my question was do you see those gmail's in your Web based Gmail (log in  and look). https://mail.google.com/mail/

Comment: No they are not in the gmail web client.  Only a handful of emails from years past are even in the web client, everything is in Apple Mail.

Comment: OK, let me try this way. You Apple Mail is like the Post man (it delivers mail) from the Post office to your Mail box (and the Gmail is the Post office). All your `gmail` copy are still in the Post office, and there it is where they show up first before the mailman delivers it to you (Apple Mail). **GMAIL is a Web based mail.**

Comment: OK how does that help address my question at all?  I already know that mail first hits gmail (duh) and then Apple Mail pulls it into the client.  This doesn't shed any light on why those emails all appear under the iCloud Inbox folder in Mail.app, rather than under the appropriate Gmail folder that is already present in the client.

Comment: You are right, it does not addresses your question, it was just clarifying your wrong statement that the Gmail is not web based. I lost my interest "discussing" further with you. Good luck.

Comment: Whatever, I never said Gmail is not web based.  I said I do not use the web based email client.  It appeared you were talking specifically about that since explicitly excluded Apple Mail, which is the only client I use.  Work on your own ability to clarify before saying someone else made a "wrong statement".

Comment: JVC, did you ever find a solution to this problem? I have been struggling with this for months and this is the *only* post that describes exactly what is happening with my accounts. (Apologies for posting this as a solution; I do not have 50 reputation, so I could not post as a comment.)

Comment: Actually you did post a comment and not a solution so, all good there!  :)  It's been so long now I don't even remember what this was exactly, but I don't seem to have it anymore. Maybe related to changing my iCloud email, it used to be one of my gmail addresses but I changed it to be my .me (iCloud) address instead.  Maybe that fixed it? I really don't know at this point I'm afraid!

Answer (score 1):

you might have an rule set-up to automatically forward mail in the client.

Comment: No, though I use lots of rules  to organize messages, I definitely do not have, nor have I ever had, any rules that forwards 100% of my emails anywhere.